# Autocomplete search by connecting to restful web service

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery.
I like to devlop an auto search box where when a user types any two letters in a country name ex: "nd" in "India" or "NewZealand" the seacrh box should get both the countries using a restful web service (returns JSON object) and suggest the user while typing nd.

Comment: Have you tried breaking the problem down into smaller pieces? Are you having trouble writing a restful service? Searching through a list of countries? Making the call to the server to get recommendations? Displaying the recommendations to the user? As it is, you're question is too broad. See [ask].

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: My get method of restful service returns list of country names like { "india", "new zealand", "United States", "indonesia" }. I already created this service.
I have a simple html form where there is a input text box where a user types a part of the country name like in, the user should be able to view india, indonesia etc. I am working on the Jquery autocomplete box where users can get the results from a web service directly when he was typing.